# Are holograms in the style of those from the Star Wars films possible?

Tags: star-wars, hologram

I'm just... curious as to whether it is actually possible to create one similar to the ones seen in *Star Wars*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in theory eventually.
https://gajitz.com/lasers-ionize-mid-air-molecules-to-make-moving-holograms/
"Japanese company Aerial Burton has moved holography in a completely new direction. They created 3D moving images in mid-air using laser plasma technology. Their technique doesn’t require fog, water, or a screen to create images; the lasers simply ionize molecules in the air. The company accomplished this using a 1kHz infrared pulse laser directed into a 3D scanner. The laser hits pre-defined points in mid-air, instantly creating short-lived pockets of plasma by ionizing molecules at the appropriate points."

See also

And different technology actually directly aiming for replicating the hologram.
https://www.gizmodo.com.au/2018/01/inside-the-princess-leia-project-star-wars-holograms-are-real-now/
https://www.nature.com/articles/nature25176
"This display works by first isolating a cellulose particle in a photophoretic trap created by spherical and astigmatic aberrations. The trap and particle are then scanned through a display volume while being illuminated with red, green and blue light."